# Canvas transformation rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d

Is there any way to apply a transformation to a canvas element (`scale` or `translate` or `setTransform`) without having to first clear the canvas and then redraw everything on it. The specific effect I have is using the mouse to drag the graph around (so just `translate` over and over with the mouse), but each time I translate I have to clear the canvas and redraw what I had on there. Ideally I would like to just call a `translate` method and have some superfast built-in method rerender the canvas for me. Once there is a sufficient amount of things to redraw, just the cost of iteration and redrawing can lead to less-than-desirable performance.

Any ideas how to increase the performance here?

Comment: I'd try [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) which allows to move objects with the mouse and seems pretty fast. Are you using `requestAnimationFrame` ?

Comment: no i am not, and unfortunately i cannot use fabric.js because this is my own project. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to redraw each time as translate, rotate and scale only sets a parameter to the canvas and doesn't do anything to the existing content. They will only apply to the next thing drawn to the canvas.

You can however try to transform using CSS instead. That will transform the canvas element including its content.

Note that you'll need to calculate counter-offset of the mouse coordinates in this case (also if you keep the transforms on the canvas itself).

Comment: thanks! this is what i was thinking. i already have what i need working, so im just looking for further optimizations. ill look into using css and see how that works, at the very least out of curiosity!